# Comparison of two sets of eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a symmetric matrix in $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. Denote its eigenvalues by $\lambda_1\leq\ldots\leq\lambda_n$. Let $B$ be a $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ matrix induced from $A$ by taking the left-upper corner of $A$. That is, $B_{i,j}=A_{i,j}$. Denote the eigenvalues of $B$ by $\mu_1\leq\ldots\leq\mu_{n-1}$. Try to show that $\lambda_1\leq\mu_1\leq\lambda_2\leq\ldots\leq\mu_{n-1}\leq\lambda_n$.

Comment: What thoughts do you have on this problem? Admittedly, I'm not sure how to do this but others might not be as receptive to it because you haven't provided your own insight. It's definitely an interesting problem though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known as the Cauchy Interlacing theorem. A proof can be found [here](http://matrix.skku.ac.kr/Series-E/Monthly-E.pdf).

Comment: Would you mind putting a PDF warning on that?